# BufferedReader sets the text file null

Tags: java, null, text-files, bufferedreader

I am trying to simply read in a line from a text file using BufferedReader. Here is the sample code:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( "data.txt") );

       while(reader.readLine() != null )
       {
          System.out.println(reader.readLine())                
       }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code above seems to not only print out null, but sets the data.txt file to null (as in, the file data.txt would initially have 40kb, and a call to readLine() sets it to 0kb)?

I have no idea why this is occurring, it can locate the file, but sets the file to null?

Can anyone identify why this is occurring?
Thanks.

EDIT !!

The BufferedWriter code is below:

```
try{
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data.txt"))

  for(int x=0; x<64; x++)
  {
     writer.write(String.valueOf(data[x]));
  }
  writer.newLine();
  writer.newLine();
  }
  catch(IOException io)
  {};
```

Comment: This code is not erasing your `data.txt` file (despite the bug others have noted); try coping `data.txt` to `data-2.txt` and changing just this snippit of code to use this new file. Review, or share, the rest of your code which deals with `data.txt` to find why it is being truncated.

Comment: OK, I have posted the sample code that used BufferedWriter

Comment: Ahhh.. BufferedWriter. Whenever buffer is involved, It is a good idea to call flush() after writing everything. If not, there maybe some data still in buffer that haven't been written to file before the file is closed.

Comment: Print your String.valueOf(data[x]) i think this is the source of your problem. Also, always flush and close your Writer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your file contents gets erased however you need to change your while loop to this since you're skipping lines if you use your code.

```
String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Ah OK, the text file seems to become erased

Comment: is that your full code? if not, post the your full code.

Comment: My code is pretty long actually. I actually have a BufferedWriter, and BufferedReader as static variables contained as class fields, and the methods that are being called are contained in class methods. Could that be something to do with it?

Comment: I think those codes related with BufferedWriter is the source of the problem. You should post your code related with that so we can see what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your first readline() is used as while loop condition. Then you write the second readline() to System.out. So you're writing every 2nd line. What you need is this.

```
String str = null;
while((str=reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. The text file is still been erased for some reason though?

Comment: Can't see where the code where it erases text. You should post the code that does that.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing every second line only, and may also print the end of file null terminator. This is because the `while` conditional reads the line from your file as well, and that you simply discard this line after checking against null.

Retain the line value in the variable:

```
   String s;
   while( (s = reader.readLine()) != null )
       {
          System.out.println(s);
       }
```

Comment: I see. The data.txt is still been erased tho? I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

you are reading one line in while loop and then again reading next line in **println** statement. that means you are when you check the condition that time **reader.readLine()** does not equal to null, but when you read in println then it become null .`

```
while(reader.readLine() != null )
   {
      System.out.println(reader.readLine())                
   }
```

you should write your code in this way:

```
String line = null;
while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
   {
      System.out.println(line) ;              
   }
```

did you close your **writer** object? you should close your writer object inside **finally** block this way.
this might help you to resolve your problem.

```
finally
{
    if(null != writer)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioException)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working sample, similar to your original. Note that closing resources is very important:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile
{
    public static final void main(String[] argv)
    {
        String fileName="data-2.txt";

        writeFile(fileName);
        readFile(fileName);
    }

    private static void writeFile(String fileName)
    {
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try
        {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));

            for(int x=0; x<64; x++)
            {
                writer.write("some data\n");
            }
            writer.newLine();
            writer.newLine();
        }
        catch(IOException x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            safeClose(writer);
        }
    }

    private static void readFile(String fileName)
    {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = null;

        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( fileName ));

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException x) 
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            safeClose(reader);
        }
    }


    private static void safeClose(Closeable closeable)
    {
        if(null != closeable)
        {
            try
            {
                closeable.close();
            }
            catch(IOException x)
            {
                //ignore -x.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```